# git grep doesn't accept -- to separate branch from filename

Tags: git

I have both a file and a branch called atlas, which trips git up when I want to search in it using git grep:

```
$ git grep asdf atlas --
fatal: ambiguous argument 'atlas': both revision and filename
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

$ git grep asdf atlas -- .
fatal: ambiguous argument 'atlas': both revision and filename
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

With git log, I can append `--` to fix it:

```
$ git log -1 --oneline atlas
fatal: ambiguous argument 'atlas': both revision and filename
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

$ git log -1 --oneline atlas --
690eca5 atlas: extra unit tests
```

How do I achieve the same result with `git grep`?

EDIT: to clarify: I want to search for `asdf` in every file in the branch called atlas.

Comment: Did you try forcing the regex with `-e`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams nice suggestion, unfortunately not the solution in this case. "asdf" is properly being recognized as the pattern; it's the next argument (atlas) which is interpreted as a branch. but still, worth a try, so thanks.

Comment: Would this work? `git grep asdf -- atlas`

Comment: That does the opposite of what I want---search for asdf in the atlas directory in HEAD. I want to search for asdf in every file in the atlas branch. question updated to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`git grep asdf atlas:`

The colon is generally used for specifying a refspec with the format `<source>:<destination>`, but you can leave the destination empty and just provide a source, which in this case makes it clear that you are referring to a branch and not a file.

You can learn more about refspecs [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec).

Comment: This is unfortunate for scripting (using xargs & co), but it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of my eternal gripes about git (too much DWIM, which sometimes mis-interprets "what I mean" when trying to do what I mean).  But there is a hacky work-around to resolve ambiguity in favor of a commit (actually you need a tree-ish but this form works for several additional cases that need commit-ish):

```
git grep asdf 'atlas^{commit}'
```

(whether you need to quote against braces depends on your shell, I put them in since they work even if you don't need them).